# Redirect index.html to index.php WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Sorry, this might be stupid question but I just can't get it to work.

I have a WordPress installation under the main domain which works perfectly. Additionally I have a second domain which points to the same webroot but requests an **index.html** instead of the default **index.php**. I tried pretty much everything I could find online but nothing seems to work. Editing the *.htaccess* did not work and when I try to create an index.html with a redirect like so

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://mainDomain.com/index.php">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://mainDomain.com/index.php"
      </script>
      <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='http://mainDomain.com'>link to example</a>
    </body>
  </html>
```

WordPress always calls the **index.html** instead of the index.php and I have an infinite loop.

Can anyone help please?